# Use new custom icon in web application

Tags: css, font-face

I used [Glyphter](https://www.glyphter.com/) to create an icon from a custom SVG file.  I am trying to use it now, hopefully something like this:

```
<i class='myIcon'></i>
```

But just adding it as a font-family to a class did not work.  I can't seem to figure out how to use it.  I have the generated CSS file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphter';
src: url('../fonts/Glyphter.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Glyphter.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/Glyphter.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/Glyphter.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Glyphter.svg#Glyphter') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[class*='icon-']:before{
    display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'Glyphter';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 1;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
.icon-clear-filter:before{content:'\0048';}
```

Comment: What's the name you've given to your icon in Glyphter?

Comment: Actually, I do not know how to name it.  all of the files all called "Glyphter"

Comment: When you're on the Glyphter website, click on your icon, on the left you have a panel to rename your icon, if you don't change any other setting, your class will be `icon-foo`, foo being the name you've chosen this panel.

Comment: I'm not sure Glypher even worked because when I click on the svg that downloaded, not thing is there.  I am trying it again now.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much!